# Make an installer for my own version of missionplanner (open source project in win form)

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer

I am making my own version of an open source project call Mission Planner (it's an app that allows to control many types of drone so I configured it to be more effictient for my drones). I am now trying to build an installer for my new app but I am struggling with some aspects.

Here's what I did so far.

Create a new setup project in the same solution, in the app folder I had a project output (the assembly appears on it's own), i created two shortcuts, on for the desktop and the other for the programs menu. Then i modified the different parameters (name, url, manufacturer etc...). Then I cleaned the solution, built the installer (everything was ok) and then I right-clicked and selected the "install". Everything was okay, I had my shortcut on the desktop and program menu.

BUT

When I try to execute the app it does not work, here is the error I have in the output window :

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
> 'MissionPlanner.MainV2' threw an exception. --->
> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. Reference
> assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be
> loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x80131058) ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a
> reference assembly for execution.    --- End of inner exception stack
> trace ---    at MissionPlanner.MAVLinkInterface..ctor()    at
> MissionPlanner.MainV2..cctor()    --- End of inner exception stack
> trace ---    at MissionPlanner.MainV2..ctor()    at
> MissionPlanner.Program.Start(String[] args)

So if anyone knows what this means I would be glad to know what is going on and if there's any solution to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

BadImageFormatException occurs if you try to load a 64 bit DLL into a 32 bit process or vice versa. Make sure you ship 64 DLLs only or 32 bit DLLs only.

The name of the exception has nothing to do with pictures. Microsoft [calls PE (Portable Executable) files images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format).

Comment: so the maximum number of dll I can put is 64 ? I am not sure I understood what you meant, where can I check the number of bits for the process and the number for the dll ?

Comment: 64 bit is the CPU architecture (64 bit = AMD64 architecture, 32 bit = Intel x86 architecture). You are compiling your program for a certain architecture. The number of DLLs is not limited.

Comment: Okey thank you ! And is it possible to change eather the cpu architecture or the dll ship ?

Comment: Yes and yes. For the architecture part, you need to check or uncheck "prefer 32 bit". For the setup part, you have provided no info at all. It's very hard to tell what you did and thus hard to make suggestions.

Comment: Hey sorry but it still not work, I've tried to add assemblies "ValueTuple.dll" by hand, to set "prefer 32 bits" on my main program, I've tried other methods, I followed tutorials and nothing change it. I still have the same error

Comment: Can you upload your installer somwehere?